# Shared Location Options in MS SQL Server Data Migration Assistant

Tags: sql-server, migration

For studying purposes I want to upgrade AdventureWorks sample database from MS SQL Server 2017 Express edition to Developer. I am using DMA for that, and can't understand the meaning of Shared Location Option. What I have to specify in that field in order to continue my migration? What's the use of backupshare?

[image]

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is for backups that can be accessed by both source and Target servers.

Think of it Just like logshipping has a backup share that is accessed by primary backup job and secondary copy jobs.

Comment: So I have to specify the folder where the backups of my old databases are kept?

Comment: you have to specify the share e.g. \\servername\backups\  which will be accessible by both servers.